# how to input an array of strings without knowing the size of the array

Tags: c-strings

I have a program who's input is n(no of input strings) followed by the strings.How do i scan the strings without knowing the size of array?

**below is the format of input**

2
Hacker
Rank

Comment: What are you trying to do with the strings? You might not need to store them all at once, depending on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: i need this output :                                                                                  
Hce akr
Rn ak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the desired output, you should only need to store two strings at a time -
 simply read the next character on the line and alternate between adding it to the first string or the second. When you hit the newline character, write out the two strings one after the other, then clear the strings and start reading characters from the beginning of the next line. That way, you don't need to worry about how many strings there are.